# Jquery onclick remove parent div

Tags: jquery

I have the following code but how can i achieve when clicking on the remove button the parent div removes?

```js
     function removeDiv(){
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div><button onClick="removeDiv()">button1</button></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><button onClick="removeDiv()">button2</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `onClick="removeDiv(this)"` and `function removeDiv(elem){
        $(elem).parent('div').remove();
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass the current element context `this`  to `removeDiv` function.

```
<div><button onClick="removeDiv(this)"></button></div>
```

Change function as

```
function removeDiv(elem){
    $(elem).parent('div').remove();
}
```

---

However as you are using jQuery, You should bind event using it, here is an example, where I have used [`Class Selector (“.class”)`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to bind event handler with elements.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.removeDiv').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="removeDiv">removeDiv</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="removeDiv">removeDiv</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

using with `jquery` simply add the click event:
like blew.Its will be remove the `closest parent div`

***Two Methods:***

```
   1.$(this).parent('div').remove();

   2.$(this).closest('div').remove();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
$('button').click(function (){
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
  //$(this).closest('div').remove(); its also working
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <div><button >remove1</button></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div><button >remove2</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```